# Different classes for different JSON messages in one try - catch block in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have four different classes for four different JSON messages. The messages always come together and I need to handle them at the same time. 
The code is in one try - catch block and I search the right class by deserializing the JSON.

```
var convertedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class>(message);
```

but this three times throw an exception ann ones successfully continue.
What I want to do is check first class, if error check another class up to four and only if no class matches throw an exception.
Is this possible in one try - catch block?

Thanks a lot

Comment: A [mcve] really would be awesome.

Comment: @Crowcoder was right. I implement checks if the JSON contains words which are specific for every JSON as Dude Pascalou did in his question in provided link and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to retry the same operation (in your case deserialization to a model) multiple times and then take a decision. You could consider using [*Polly.Retry*](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#step-2--specify-how-the-policy-should-handle-those-faults) for this purpose. See the linked documentation for an example